# How to generate a dynamic URL/View on C#/JavaScript without creating many specific views?

Tags: javascript, c#, url, dynamic, path

I'm making some kind of music explorer, let's say this is my url:

```
https://localhost:44322/Music/ListOfArtists.aspx
```

And of course there are many artists and I'd want to be able to generate a view that works for every artist, instead of creating a view for each artist. I can create a general view and just modify the data displayed in the page, so the url would look like this:

```
https://localhost:44322/Music/ListOfArtists/Artist.aspx
```

But I want the URL to also show the name of the artist instead of Artist.aspx like:

```
https://localhost:44322/Music/ListOfArtists/Eagles.aspx
https://localhost:44322/Music/ListOfArtists/ABBA.aspx
```

It'd also mean that whenever I type the name of the artist on the URL I'd get redirected to such artist, I remember I ever did something like this many years ago using PHP and JavaScript but can't remember exactly neither know how to achieve this using C#, but I used something like this somewhere:

```
url/{menu_id}/{artist_id}
```

Do you know how can I do this?

Comment: Hi there. Please take a moment to [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and modify your question accordingly.

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET MVC (which the C# tag at least somewhat implies) then having parameters in the route like that is standard functionality.  You might start with some tutorials on ASP.NET MVC and see how they manage parameters like that.  Usually integer values are used, but strings can be used as well.